# How to remove code signing in Xcode?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I've created an iOS7 project in Xcode 5.  It's a very simple app.  I zipped it and sent it to another developer.  When they open it, they get these messages:

> No matching code signing identity found
>
> No code signing identities (i.e.certificate and private key pairs)
>   matching "iPhone Developer" were found.  Xcode can resolve this issue
>   by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

How do they get around this? The app isn't going to be submitted to the app store.

Is this happening because they have not linked Xcode to their online developer account?  Isn't an online developer account free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other developer can ignore that message if the intention is to run the app on the Simulator. But you *must* use code signing in order to run an app from Xcode on a device, even for testing purposes, even if the app is never going to be submitted to the App Store. And that costs $99/year. End of story.

You could turn your account into a Company account and put this developer on your company; that way the developer is covered under your $99.

Or, if you just want to send the app to someone for testing and you don't need them to run the app directly from Xcode on a device, you can create an Ad Hoc build targeted to their device.

And of course the developer can look at your code, test on the simulator, and run your previously built Ad Hoc build on the device - but not run *from Xcode* on the device, i.e. the developer can not *build* for a device without *someone* paying that $99/year fee.

Comment: And as I say in my book (http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_running_on_a_device): "Yes, this is infuriating. Now get over it."